# SVD error when deciding where to put the negative in the eigenvector

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, svd

I am computing the SVD of the matrix
$$
A = 
\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 2 \\\ -1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}
$$

I know that $A = U\Sigma V^T$. I am getting a confusing result when considering one of the eigenvectors and where to put the negation sign.

For the eigenvectors of
$$
A^TA = \begin{bmatrix} 5 & 3 \\\ 3 & 5 \end{bmatrix}
$$
which has eigenvalues $\lambda_1 = 2$ and $\lambda_2 = 8$.

I find that, for the $\lambda_1$, the eigenvector $\vec{v}_1 = \begin{pmatrix} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\\ -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\end{pmatrix}$. However, when I finish the remaining working (which I have left out, as they appear correct), then when I use this eigenvector, I get
$$
U\Sigma V^T = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix} 2\sqrt{2} & 0 \\\ 0 & \sqrt{2} \end{bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\\ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \end{bmatrix}^T = \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 2 \\\ 1 & -1 \end{bmatrix} \neq A
$$

I see that if I instead used the negation of $\vec{v}_1$, I get
$$
U\Sigma V^T = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix} 2\sqrt{2} & 0 \\\ 0 & \sqrt{2} \end{bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\\ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \end{bmatrix}^T = \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 2 \\\ -1 & 1 \end{bmatrix} =  A
$$

My professor insists it is fine to use an eigenvector $(x, -y)$ or $(-x, y)$, but the final calculation is not equal to $A$, and I cannot understand why. Why is this going wrong? How can I avoid this?

Comment: Quick comment: notice that in every EVD there is a sign ambiguity. Meaning that the negative of an eigenvector is also an eigenvector, since $A= \sum_i \lambda_i u_i u_i^\top = \sum_i \lambda_i (-u_i) (-u_i^\top)$.

Comment: @VanBaffo Yeah, I do understand that. I have tried to reason about this from every angle I can, but cannot understand why I am arriving at the incorrect solution.

Comment: I guess in the first case you have the wrong $U$. The correct one is $diag(1,-1)$. Indeed $(0,1)$ is also an eigenvector of $AA^T$.

Comment: @Desperado It seems our lecturer I'll-explained the calculation of U. Upon exploring additional resources, I see now that he was wrong, which has caused this whole mess. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when I finish the remaining working (which I have left out, as they appear correct),...

What *appears* correct may not be really correct. The left singular vector corresponding to the right singular pair $\left(\sqrt{2},\,(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})^T\right)$ is
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}A\pmatrix{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\ -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}=\pmatrix{0\\ -1}.
$$
Therefore, if you take the second row of $V^T$ as $(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})$, you should take the second column of $U$ as $(0,-1)^T$.

Comment: You're correct. My lecturer incorrectly taught us how to find U, saying we had to solve similarly to V, computing its eigenvectors. Thankfully I realised here and through utilising alternative resources that it was there the error was residing. Edit: technically the U I had was correct with a different V, which is why I carelessly claimed that statement